# How to use Windows Small Business Server 2008 to print from a web application?

Tags: windows, printing, windows-server-2008-r2, network-printer, print-server

I'm developing a web application in PHP and we need to print some files/labels from this web application. The web application is hosted on a 3rd party hosting provider. The thermal printers are available in the intranet which can be accessed via Windows SBS 2008.

The windows SBS 2008 can be accessed through a public domai/IP. IIS is currently running on the same server.

Is there any way to print the files from Internet by sending a command to the SBS server, something like API request with authentication?

Please note: I have limited access to the system, so installing any softwares on SBS server is not practical.

Comment: So the server has to be connected to the same network as the printers.

Comment: The windows server is in the network where the printers are. But the application is hosted on a different dedicated server environment. If all of theme were on same network, the answer is straight forward. But confused with current scenario. Any ways?

Comment: I don't understand what your attempting to print exactly.

Comment: Some label created from the web application dynamically.

Comment: If its a web application, why can't you visit it within a browser, and print it off like any website?

Comment: I need the ability to assign the printers using g my application. Also the labels should be printed automatically without user interaction. That's why I'm looking for such a solution.